# AIX Samba user access getpwuid failed

Tags: samba, kerberos, ibm, aix

I have installed Samba `4.12.10` via yum in AIX `7.2`. I have also installed kerberos package to authenticate samba with kerberos.

My objective is to allow users access of folders/files in AIX from their windows machines.

```
# yum list installed | grep samba
samba.ppc 4.12.10-2 @AIX_Toolbox_72
samba-client.ppc 4.12.10-2 @AIX_Toolbox_72
samba-common.ppc 4.12.10-2 @AIX_Toolbox_72
samba-devel.ppc 4.12.10-2 @AIX_Toolbox_72
samba-libs.ppc 4.12.10-2 @AIX_Toolbox_72
samba-winbind.ppc 4.12.10-2 @AIX_Toolbox_72
samba-winbind-clients.ppc 4.12.10-2 @AIX_Toolbox_72

# yum list installed | grep winbin
samba-winbind.ppc 4.12.10-2 @AIX_Toolbox_72
samba-winbind-clients.ppc 4.12.10-2 @AIX_Toolbox_72

# yum list installed | grep krb5
krb5-devel.ppc 1.18.3-1 @AIX_Toolbox
krb5-libs.ppc 1.18.3-1 @AIX_Toolbox
krb5-server.ppc 1.18.3-1 @AIX_Toolbox
krb5-server-ldap.ppc 1.18.3-1 @AIX_Toolbox
krb5-workstation.ppc 1.18.3-1 @AIX_Toolbox
```

However, when I try to access the AIX server in windows file explorer: `\\pc96p9` (pc96p9 is my AIX machine name)
It is showing access is denied even through a correct domain username and password is provided.

Then I checked the samba log from `/etc/samba/log.10.161.139.74` (10.161.139.74 is the windows machine accessing AIX), I get the following error:

```
[2021/03/26 12:07:51.353238, 0] ../../source3/auth/token_util.c:567(add_local_groups)
add_local_groups: SID S-1-5-21-2693943023-2014060074-1703039353-34220 -> getpwuid(100000) failed, is nsswitch configured?
[2021/03/26 12:07:51.353328, 3] ../../source3/auth/token_util.c:403(create_local_nt_token_from_info3)
Failed to add local groups
[2021/03/26 12:07:51.353351, 1] ../../source3/auth/auth_generic.c:174(auth3_generate_session_info_pac)
Failed to map kerberos pac to server info (NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER)
[2021/03/26 12:07:51.353424, 3] ../../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3280(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] || at ../../source3/smbd/smb2_sesssetup.c:146
[2021/03/26 12:07:51.354653, 3] ../../source3/smbd/server_exit.c:250(exit_server_common)
Server exit (NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET)
```

Here is my `/etc/krb5.conf`:

```
[logging]
default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
default_realm = MY-OA.MY.ORG.HK
dns_lookup_realm = false
dns_lookup_kdc = false
ticket_lifetime = 24h
renew_lifetime = 7d
forwardable = true

[realms]
MY-OA.MY.ORG.HK = {
kdc = MYIFS28.MY-OA.MY.ORG.HK
admin_server = MYIFS28.MY-OA.ORG.HK
}

[domain_realm]
.my.org.hk = MY.ORG.HK
my.org.hk = MY.ORG.HK
```

Here is my `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
[global]
        realm = my-oa.my.org.hk
        netbios name = pc96p9
        workgroup = MY-OA
        realm = MY-OA.MY.ORG.HK
        password server = 10.67.1.92
        server services = rpc, nbt, wrepl, ldap, cldap, kdc, drepl, winbind, ntp_signd, kcc, dnsupdate, dns, s3fs
        security = ads
        idmap uid = 100000-200000
        idmap gid = 100000-200000
        template homedir = /home/%U
        template shell = /usr/bin/bash
        winbind use default domain = yes
        winbind offline logon = false
        winbind enum users = yes
        winbind enum groups = yes
        domain master = no
        local master = no
        preferred master = no
        socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_KEEPALIVE SO_SNDBUF=32768 SO_RCVBUF=32768
        os level = 0
        wins server = 10.67.1.92
        encrypt passwords = yes
        server signing = auto
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        log level = 3
        max log size = 50

[data]
        comment = Public Data Share
        path = /data1/winshare
        public = yes
        writable = yes
        inherit acls = yes
        inherit permissions = yes
        printable = no
```

And here is my `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
passwd:     files winbind
shadow:     files winbind
group:      files winbind
hosts:     files dns wins
```

Actually, we have samba `3.6` running fine in a AIX `7.1` production environment, the above 3 configuration files are directly copied from AIX `7.1` (samba `3.6`) to the new AIX `7.2` (samba `4.12`).

Can anyone please let me know if there is anything wrong in my samba configuration? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Having come across a similar error in a completely different environment, I can only offer this as a suggestion, not a solution, but…

The error message says that the Windows-style Security Identifier (SID) `S-1-5-21-2693943023-2014060074-1703039353-34220` is being mapped to the Unix-style user identifier (UID) `100000`. This mapping is apparently incorrect; it was probably right in the old environment but needs to be modified in the new one.

Since it appears you’re using `winbindd`, you should be able to both identify the user in question, and correct the mapping, using [`wbinfo`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/wbinfo.1.html). I’m not using `winbindd`, so I haven’t tested this myself, but it should start with something like:

```
$ wbinfo -s S-1-5-21-2693943023-2014060074-1703039353-34220
```